# Trying to get the length of lists from a list and their count based on length of each list

Tags: python, list

am trying to get the length of list and their count in a given list

for ex:

```
l1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['c', 'd', 'f'],['g', 'h', 't', 'j']]
```

output:

```
a_3 = 2
b_4  = 1
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what exactly do you wish to find out? The question isn't clear.

Comment: @DavidS Hey I already got it, anyway I was trying to get the count of different list lengths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is:

```
from collections import Counter
l = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 't', 'j']]
counts = Counter(map(len,l))
```

`map` will iterate over the nested lists inside `l` and apply `len` to each of them, then `Counter` will save each returned length as key and the amount of repetition of that length.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the list elements and create a dictionary with counts as:

```
l1 = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 't', 'j']]
res = dict()
for k in l1:
    if len(k) not in res:
        res[len(k)] = 1
    else:
        res[len(k)] += 1
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{3: 2, 4: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a_4 = 0
a_3 = 0
for i in mylist:
    if len(i) == 4:
        a_4 += 1
    else:
        a_3 += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can streamline things a bit more by using a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_of_lists = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['c', 'd', 'f'],['g', 'h', 't', 'j']]
list_counter = defaultdict(int)

for one_list in list_of_lists:
    list_counter[len(one_list)] += 1


print(list_counter)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {3: 2, 4: 1})
```